# Parsing Play Framework 2 JSON request body

Tags: json, playframework-2.0

I have a very simple class that represents the request body:

```
public class AddSubscription {
    @Constraints.Required
    public Integer subscriptionPlanId;

    @Constraints.Required
    public YearMonthDate validFrom;

    public YearMonthDate validTo;
}

public class YearMonthDate {
    @Constraints.Required
    public Integer year;

    @Constraints.Required
    public Integer month;

    @Constraints.Required
    public Integer day;
}
```

Now, using JSON BodyParser I need to get the request data:

```
Form<AddSubscription> form = Form.form(AddSubscription.class).bindFromRequest();

if (form.hasGlobalErrors() || form.hasErrors()) {
    return badRequest();
}
```

The problem is, *validFrom* and *validTo* are always null :(

Below are the contents of the request as seen by body parser:

What am I missing?

[image: Body Parser contents]

Comment: Would you post client side and the way you make a request?

Comment: It is not a client side issue. It is Play :( See http://www.stupidjavatricks.com/2013/04/play-framework-2-1-the-bloom-is-off-the-rose/, section *Do It Yourself JSON Parsing*

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be limitation of Play.

I ended up with the solution given here [Play 2.1 Addendum](http://www.stupidjavatricks.com/2013/04/play-2-1-addendum/)